# "and/or" in an extended list

Tags: conjunctions

I'm having a problem with "and/or" as I write technical descriptions for audience segments. Audience segments are people who have been put in a group based on similar interests, attributes or behaviours.

An example of what a segment currently looks like:

Segment Name: *Finance Enthusiasts*

Segment Description: *These are people who: have read articles related to stocks, bonds, dividends or investments; and/or have read the finance section on Finance Journal at least once in the past 30 days; and/or have an interest in Credit Card or Loan products.*

The data scientists I work with have stressed that and/or is necessary as each attribute is both inclusive **and** exclusive in defining a segment. So people in the group may exhibit one of these attributes, or any combination of them.

I only have roughly 50 words to work with. Is there a more elegant way to phrase this, without becoming over-verbose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a more elegant way of removing the need to use **and/or**:

> Segment Description: *These are people who* **have done one or more of the following***: read articles related to stocks, bonds, dividends or investments; read the finance section on Finance Journal at least once in the past 30 days;* or **shown an** *interest in Credit Card or Loan products.*

In addition to moving *have* before the colon, I have also rephrased the last list item in order to maintain a parallel structure with the other items. There is a slight difference in meaning between *having* an interest in something and *showing* an interest in something, but since you are only describing observable behaviour anyway, it seems to me the change would be okay. (Although you might prefer *expressed* to *shown*.)

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly the kind of thing I needed to eliminate the 'and/or' problem. And yes it is just observable behaviour, so having and showing an interest are similar enough to be interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would phrase it like:

*These are people who have read articles related to stocks, bonds, dividends or investments; have read the finance section on Finance Journal at least once in the past 30 days; and/or have an interest in Credit Card or Loan products.*

The first "and/or" is redundant. The repeating "have"s make me a bit iffy too but subtracting the last one makes it read weird so they do stay. I wish you luck!